# Sending data from BPF to user space side and waiting for it's analysis result

Tags: security, linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf

I'm currently trying to write a fanotify wannabe program using libbpf + bpf LSM hooks.

What I'm trying to achieve here is to intercept a LSM event(for  example **lsm.s/file_open**) and to send event data to user space side.
On user-side I'd do some analysis and return a verdict that will be passed back to LSM module.

I know that it was not possible yet several years ago, but in recent patches sleepable bpf programs were added and they work with LSM hooks.
But I still don't know if I can block bpf side until analysis results are ready.
So is it possible yet?

At the current state I managed only to basically read into user ringbuf some statistics, but that's not exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I guess allocating a structure for user-space return result and checking it for a valid response returned by bpf_copy_from_user() in a cycle can be it, but I would like to hear some thoughts on that.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

This isn't yet possible. Sleepable BPF programs were intended for special cases where e.g. helper execution may be interrupted; see for example [the `bpf_copy_from_user_task` helper](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html). Sleepable BPF programs cannot simply sleep while waiting for input from userspace.

Depending on what you want to do with the userspace verdict, it may be possible to read it from a later program execution.